# in illustrator javascript to ungroup and group

Tags: javascript

illustrator in .ai file i am having layer name as "Layer1" inside this layer i am having group named as  " rename" this rename group i have to ungroup and move it to new group .can anybody please  help me   in javascript for this , i have also attached image.

[layer 1  image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wicVR.jpg) ,[rename group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLufZ.jpg)

```
var itemKinds = new Array("pathItems","compoundPathItems","textFrames","placedItems","rasterItems","meshItems","pluginItems","graphItems","symbolItems","groupItems");

function getChildAll(obj)
{
    var childsArr = new Array();
    for(var i=0;i<obj.pageItems.length;i++)childsArr.push(obj.pageItems[i]);
    return childsArr;
}


if(app.activeDocument)
{
    doc = app.activeDocument;
    if(doc.groupItems.length)for(var i=0;i<doc.layers.length;i++)ungroup(doc.layers[i]);
}

function ungroup(obj)
{
    var elements = getChildAll(obj);
    if(elements.length<1){
        obj.remove();
        return;
    }else{
        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
        {
            try{
                if(elements[i].parent.typename!="Layer 1")elements[i].moveBefore(obj);
                if(elements[i].typename=="rename")ungroup(elements[i]);
            }catch(e){

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The typename is "GroupItem", so you should change:

```
if(elements[i].typename=="rename")ungroup(elements[i]);
```

back to:

```
if(elements[i].typename=="GroupItem")ungroup(elements[i]);
```

This sample code was originally to ungroup all groups. If you only want to ungroup the "rename" group, then change this line:

```
if(doc.groupItems.length)for(var i=0;i<doc.layers.length;i++)ungroup(doc.layers[i]);
```

to:

```
ungroup(doc.groupItems['rename']);
```

Finally, to move the items into a "new group", you have to create a group item, like:

```
var newGroup = doc.groupItems.add();
```

and move the elements inside it by replacing:

```
elements[i].moveBefore(obj);
```

with:

```
elements[i].move(newGroup,ElementPlacement.INSIDE);
```